# What's the magic of NSAutoreleasePool in Objective-C/cocoa framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I found an example of Objective-C/cocoa framework has the following code.

```
int main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Create an array
    NSArray *month = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@ ... nill];

    [pool drain];
}
```

- Q1 : What's the magic behind this (Why do I need to have the NSAutoreleasePool code?)? What magic is happening between the `NSAutoreleasePool` and `pool drain` block? I see I don't need to release`*month` myself. Is this because it's inside the `NSAutoreleasePool` and `pool drain` block?
- Q2 : With Xcode, I'm already given the main() function. In this case, how can I use the `NSAutoreleasePool` and `pool drain`?

For example :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[[NSAutoreleasePool] alloc] init];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1: The magic is that NSObject -autorelease instance method calls NSAutoreleasePool +addObject: class method. The NSObject instance is pooled in the current NSAutoreleasePool instance. And NSAutoreleasePool -drain instance method calls release method of pooled instances.

It is not the exactly same between Cocoa implementation of Apple and GNUstep, but it is similar.

- [NSObject.m](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSObject.m?revision=HEAD&view=markup&pathrev=HEAD)
- [NSAutoreleasePool.m](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSAutoreleasePool.m?view=markup&dir_pagestart=50&pathrev=HEAD)

I'm not sure why month is not released, it should be release by drain.

Q2: You can use NSAutoreleasePool wherever you want to use at. Instantiate a NSAutoreleasePool means the current pool will be changed by the new instance. drain will go back the current pool to the previous instance.

Besides NSApplicationMain never returns. It calls the exit function to exit the application and terminate the process.

Comment: I didn't call -autorelease explicitly. Is this called implicitly?

Comment: Yes as @Prairiedogg said. arrayWithObjects calls autorelease internally.

Answer (score 3):

Q1:

You don't need to release the `month` instance in the example you give because the `NSArray` class method you're calling (`arrayWithObjects:`) returns an instance that is autoreleased.  By convention in Cocoa, class methods that start with the name of the class will return autoreleased instances of that class.  These examples:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Holla %@", @"back girl!", nil];
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Holla", @"back", @"girl!", nil];
```

Will both return instances of their respective objects that are autoreleased.

Comment: Then, I think I don't need `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];` code as  `NSArray *month = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@ ... nill];` will be autoreleased anyway. Is it correct?

Comment: @prosseek: No. Autoreleasing an object puts it into the topmost autorelease pool. In `main`, no other autorelease pool exists but those you create; therefore, you need to create a pool to (implicitly) autorelease the array into. Otherwise, you will get a log message in your console log, and the array (having no autorelease pool to release it) will be leaked.

Comment: If there isn't an autoreleasepool for autoreleased objects such as the variable `month' in your comment, the object is never released, and causes a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Objective C, but let me give this a crack:

The autorelease pool is a way for Objective C to handle garbage collection in a somewhat easier way than manually.

It does this by counting references, or in this case every time you call "retain" or "release".

So if you have an instance of an object in "a", you could do:

This puts it into the AutoreleasePool:
`[a autorelease];`

This tells the autorelease pool that you want to hold on to it for a while:
`[a retain];`

When you call `[pool drain]` now, it will notice that you have one reference to a, and it won't deallocate the memory. However, if you later call `[a release]`, the next time `[pool drain]` is called, it'll see that there are no further references to a remaining, and deallocate the memory.

I have a sneaking suspicion that I just talked myself in circles without making a whole lot of sense, but here is the wikipedia article on reference counting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting

Comment: Autoreleasing is different from garbage collection; GC requires no extra code. `retain` and `release` have nothing to do with an autorelease pool; `autorelease` adds the receiver to the topmost autorelease pool on the autorelease pool stack, so that when that pool is drained, the pool will send it a `release` message.

Comment: Essential reading: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/

Comment: This is close, but it's wrong in some important details. For example, it's incorrect to say that "(the autorelease pool) counts references" or that `[a retain]` "tells the autorelease pool that you want to hold on to it". The fundamental operations of reference counting are `retain` and `release`; they do not involve the autorelease pool at all. `autorelease` is simply a way of deferring a `release` call until later (specifically, until the next `[pool drain]`. Read the reference provided by Peter Hosey, then read it again :-)

Comment: Thank's for the clarification. Like I said, I'm pretty darn new to Objective C (and compiled language at that.) I'm just glad I got it close :)